# SQL UNION error message when merging two tables

Tags: sql, union

I worked on a SQL problem:
Table: MyNumbers

| Column Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| num | int |

There is no primary key for this table. It may contain duplicates.
Each row of this table contains an integer.

A single number is a number that appeared only once in the MyNumbers table.

Write an SQL query to report the largest single number. If there is no single number, report null.

Example 1:

Input:
MyNumbers table:

| num |
| --- |
| 8 |
| 8 |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 1 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Output:

| num |
| --- |
| 6 |

Explanation: The single numbers are 1, 4, 5, and 6.
Since 6 is the largest single number, we return it.

I tried to use UNION to solve this problem:

```
SELECT num
FROM MyNumbers
GROUP BY num
HAVING COUNT(num)=1
ORDER BY num DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS num
LIMIT 1
```

Here is what I thought:
If there exists a single number, return the largest one. If there is no single number, return NULL.

But the compiler showed an error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL
> SELECT NULL AS num
> LIMIT 1' at line 7

I am new to SQL and I don't know where the problem is. Can someone help?

Comment: Hi, You need to add order by at the end.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a UNION query, the ORDER BY clause needs to go at the end of all of the unioned SELECT statements.

Eg.

```
SELECT 
  num
FROM MyNumbers 
GROUP BY num 
HAVING COUNT(num)=1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT
  NULL AS num
ORDER BY num DESC    <-- ORDER BY goes here, after all UNIONs
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the UNION ALL before GROUP By like so

I added also more duplicates to show that it works

```
CREATE TABLE MyNumbers
    (`num` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO MyNumbers
    (`num`)
VALUES
    (8),
    (8),
    (3),
    (3),
    (1),
    (4),
    (5),
    (6)
;
```

> ```
> Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT num
FROM ( SELECT num FROm MyNumbers UNION ALL SELECT NULL) numi
GROUP BY num
HAVING COUNT(num)=1 OR num IS NULL
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 1
```

| num |
| --- |
| 6 |

```
INSERT INTO MyNumbers
    (`num`)
VALUES
(1),
    (4),
    (5),
    (6)
```

> ```
> Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT num
FROM ( SELECT num FROm MyNumbers UNION ALL SELECT NULL) numi
GROUP BY num
HAVING COUNT(num)=1 OR num IS NULL
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 1
```

| num |
| --- |
| *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-lDBrkuU)

Comment: I put limit by 1 is because I only want to return 1 single number if there are multiple. Also after I union it with null row, if there exists single numbers, I don't want the null row included.

Comment: @YinanWu I edited my answer, so you can see how it can work